# What does kill 0 do actually?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, kill

In the `man page`, it says:

```
          0      All processes in the current process group are signaled
```

And I tried like this:

```
$ man kill &
[1] 15247
$
[1]+  Stopped                 man kill
$ kill 0
$ ps
15247 pts/41   00:00:00 man
```

As I understood, `kill 0` will kill all processes in the current process, which includes `pid15247`. However, it didn't do anything in this example. Does anyone have ideas about how to use it?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @FatalError I'm using Bash

Comment: See also the [Unix.SE clone of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67532/what-does-kill-0-do-actually "What does kill 0 do actually?").

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a note how `kill 0` behaves in my kill man page (debian).

But I have two comments:

(1) "Process Group" might not be what you expect. You can display the Process Group ID (PGID) with `ps -o "%p %P %r %c %a"`:

```
$ ps -o "%p %P %r %c %a"
  PID  PPID  PGID COMMAND         COMMAND
12124 12123 12124 zsh             -zsh
12212 12124 12212 man             man kill
12226 12212 12212 less            less
12302 12124 12302 ps              ps -o %p %P %r %c %a
```

So, the `man` together with the displaying pager tool (`less`) is in the same process group, but that is different from that of the shell (zsh in my case).

(2) There are probably two different `kill` commands. One built into `bash` (see bash(1), Section "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS") and the external `/bin/kill`. These two may behave differently! You can explicitly state which one you want to run by typing `builtin kill` or `command kill` instead of `kill`. The external command you can also run by specifying the path: `/bin/kill`.

Comment: `PPID` is the *parent* process ID, which is often, but not necessarily, the process group ID. The correct column is `PGID`, which does not appear in the default `ps` output; you need to use the `-o` option to construct a custom format that includes it.

Comment: @chepner: You are absolutely right, thanks! I was confused by my Cygwin's ps(1) man page, which states: "-l, --long: show process uids, ppids, pgids, winpids". Shame on me, I edited my answer accordingly. However, my statement (only man+pager have the same PGID) is correct now, as intended. (Before even that sentence was wrong `:-(`)

Comment: Under a bash interactive prompt, `command kill` does not seem to bypass the builtin kill: `command -v kill` does not return `/bin/kill`, and `command kill --help` errors out (because the builtin has no `--help`, you ought to do `help kill`) while `env kill --help` or `/bin/kill --help` works.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you have two processes involved:

1. Your shell.
2. The `man` process that you put into background.

How exactly the `kill` command works depends on your shell, but, in most cases, it is a shell builtin, which, basically, simply invokes the [`kill(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall. As you read in the man page, `0` is a special value that means “send the signal to all processes in the current process group”. So, when you type `kill 0` you send `SIGTERM` (which is the default signal) to all processes in the *current* process group.

Now, the real question here is: what is the *current* process group? Long story short, [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) are used by shells to control shell pipelines (things like `/bin/echo hello | /usr/bin/wc -c`). When your shell runs a new command, it will create a *new* process group for the processes that a part of this command (e.g. in my example above it will create a proces group with two processes: `echo` and `wc`).

So, in your example, the shell will create a new process group for the `man` process that it starts (and all its children), you can see it by running:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm
```

(PPID is the parent PID, PGID is the process group).

And then you type `kill 0` in your shell, which is in a process group of its own (remember, it created a *new* process group for `man`). So all that happens is `SIGTERM` is delivered to all processes in your shell’s process group, which is only the shell itself (and it ignores the `SIGTERM`).

Answer (score 2):

To stop all of your processes and log yourself off, enter:

```
kill -kill 0
```

This sends signal 9, the SIGKILL signal, to all processes having a process group ID equal to the senders process group ID. Because the shell cannot ignore the SIGKILL signal, this also stops the login shell and logs you off

This is IBM's AIX Manual, but perhaps the concept applies.

***This functionality does not exist in Linux "kill"*** (as I can see); but this is how it's "kill" behaves:

Killing 0 isn't killing the pid 0. Instead it is an option in kill to kill all processes in the ***current group***. With your command you are killing everything in the process group ID (GID) of the shell that issued the kill command.